# Electric current dependence of electron energy/seed

Tags: electricity, particle-detectors

As described [here](https://indico.cern.ch/event/843083/attachments/1954473/3246009/L1_signals_in_particle_detectors_riegler_2019.pdf) (page 11) the electric current is due to a moving charge  and not by a "collection" of charge by some electrode. I understood that claim but I did not understand how the electron's (or other charged particle) energy/speed affect the current. If the current is about moving charge particles so it must be related to it's kinetic energy.

[image]

Mathematical/verbal explanations is welcomed.

Comment: Look at [page 20 of an older version of the slides](https://indico.cern.ch/event/40444/attachments/810356/1110548/detector_seminar_Werner_Riegler.pdf).

Comment: @Farcher Thanks!